Docksal Configuration
My question is how can I overwrite the docksal project configuration, which is by default the name of the root folder.
My root folder contains "dots" like "org.example.project1" and I want to keep it. BUT now since Docksal version: v1.19.0 dots are not allowed anymore.
So I want to simply overwrite the default name for projects.

The answer is soo simple.
Simple add to he docksal.env file the name of he project without the dots like:
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=org-example-project1

